# What is the best way to refactor Utility class in java (static classes)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, immutability

I am thinking about refactoring some of our utility class(static classes).
Static classes are very hard to test and the main problem is that its making 
Our code very tightly coupled , a lot of dependency.
What is the best design pattern to use for refactoring ?
I thought about immutable object with a builder, but I am not sure

consider this code as 1 I want to refactor

```
public class UtilTest {

    public static boolean  isEligibleItem(Item item){
         if(isCondition1(item)){
             return isCondition2(item);
         }

         return false;
    }

    public static  boolean  isCondition1(Item item){
        //go to service that go to the data base  
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean  isCondition2(Item item){
        //go to service that go to the data base  
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I want to test my  isEligibleItem() method I need to mock the 2 method that go to db .
I can not do it as they are static . I want to avoid using Powermock

Comment: If your utility classes do not keep a state, they should remain static. How can it be hard to test static methods?

Comment: The builder pattern is useful for creating immutable objects, providing the values of member variables to the builder. Your static utility class most likely does not have member variables, so a builder would not be very useful.

Comment: Static "utility" classes are easy to test, what is you issue when testing them

Comment: Maybe an example would be useful. Can you show us?

Comment: Sometimes you want to mock them, they might be troublesome to do so.

Comment: can you show some code? it's hard to provide a response without an idea of what the code is doing

Comment: Without concrete code to discuss, this question is unclear or too broad. If you do have concrete code to discuss, then you may be better off asking on [codereview.se].

Comment: I can not do  mocking . as other developer calling other static method from theirs method

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, static methods are easy to test. Methods calling static methods, on the other hand...are not.

Comment: edit my question (adding some code) off course my code is more complicated ....

Comment: Using Java 8 you can easily provide a `Predicate<WhatEver>` to your classes, which also easily can be mocked. You then are free to simply instantiate such a class with a method reference to the needed static method.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose While that technically works, I would hate to read code like that.

Answer (score 7):

#### The Utility Class Anti-Pattern

The reason that people say *static methods are hard to test* is more about how it **tightly couples** unrelated classes together over time and it **reduces cohesion** as well as introducing i**nvisible side effects**. *These three things are way more important than some unit test hand waving complaints*

#### Testing Interactions

It is more about testing the interactions with other code than testing the `static` method itself. This is where Java really needed `Functions` as first class objects to begin with.

Classes with nothing but `static` methods are definitely a code smell in most cases. There are exceptions, but this anti-pattern tends to get abused by beginners and old timers from non-object oriented languages.

#### Exceptions to the Rule - Immutable

The exceptions are mainly things that might be considered *missing* from a class that is marked `final` like `String` that are `Immutable`.

Having a `Strings` class that has generalized `static` methods is not so bad because `String` is immutable ( no side effects ) and you can not add anything to the `String` class so you do not have many alternatives. Same goes with `Integer` and the like, `Guava` has this naming convention and it is works for these immutable objects.

#### Side Effects

`static` methods tend to introduce lots of side effects. Things that take an object and manipulate that object in some opaque manner are bad, worse is when they then look up other objects and manipulate them as well based on the instance that was passed in, they obfuscate what is going on and are tightly coupled and low cohesion.

#### High Cohesion

Tight Cohesion is not talked about as much as Coupling, but it is just as important. They are two sides of the same coin and ignoring one causes the other to suffer as a result.

These `static` methods **should be on the classes that they are taking as an argument**, they are tightly coupled to those classes. In this case why are they not on the `Item` class?

As soon as you add another `static` method that takes `SomeOtherItem` you have indirectly coupled un-related classes together.

The easiest way to remediate this is to move things closer to where they belong in this case to the `Item` class.

#### Factory/Provider Pattern

If you have things that really are `general` or thing that can not be added to a class because it is `final` or some other reason, working with interfaces and `Provider` Pattern is your best approach using a `Factory` to produce the `Provider` instances is even better.

Then you can use something like `Guice` to inject whatever implementation you need depending on if it is a test or not.

There is even a hybrid `Utility` Pattern that can have the implementation injected from a `Provider` that will give you the convenience of the `static` methods and the flexibility and maintainability of not having it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple translation to a more testable setup would be:

```
public class UtilTest {

    private final MyDatabaseService service;

    public UtilTest(MyDatabaseService service) {
       this.service = service;
    }

    public boolean  isEligibleItem(Item item){
         if(isCondition1(item)){
             return isCondition2(item);
         }
         return false;
    }

    public boolean isCondition1(Item item){
        this.service.goToDataBase();
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isCondition2(Item item){
        this.service.goToDataBase2();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't eliminate all the problems but it's a start, you can test your class with a mocked up database service.

If you want to push things further, you can declare an interface with all the methods you want `UtilTest` to expose (you might want to rename the class as well...), and make `UtilTest` implement it. All the code using `UtilTest` should be rewritten to use the interface instead, and then you can mock `UtilTest` completely and directly. Whether this is worthwhile depends a lot on how complicated `UtilTest` is in reality. If the tasks it performs are relatively simple, you'll probably think it's more hassle than it's worth. If however there's some heavy processing going in there, you'd definitely want to make it easily mockable.

Comment: Yes Its a good start(dependence injection ). but our utils class depend on others  Services and I don't want that my constructor will be too big. this is whyI thought on immutable and builder as I could built just what I want and then run it and test it

Comment: @MosheTsabari I can only go with the example code you posted. If you depend on multiple services, I'd probably think about splitting the util class up into simpler parts.

Comment: Yes u are right the root problem is that we have too much logic inside 1 Class. we need to distribute the responsibility . thanks

Comment: @MosheTsabari it seems like these utility classes are not utility classes at all.  Utility classes deal with non-business logic type code.  If you are cotnacting services, then its probrably not a utility class and should be baked into the objects that deal with these services.

Comment: @JoseMartinez Or they should be turned into higher level services themselves.

Comment: This is the problem I am dealing with . some developer wants to create method and use them without creating instances. so they push them to the most likely Utility classes they find and now we need to refactor all ..

Comment: @MosheTsabari You should convince them not to do it. If you're having trouble convincing them, that's a question for [martialarts.stackexchange.com](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com) :)